# How to add a current limit for a dual rails power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I want to make an adjustable power supply with -18 V and 18 V separately adjustable outputs. I found this [circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248953/dual-variable-power-supply-with-lm337-and-lm317) might be the best and simplest one to do the job.

How can I limit the output current to around 500-750 mA? Or should I just use an efuse?

[image: filter capacitors before current control phase]

For the transformer I was planning to use a 24V center tapped, but if it isn't enough to get an 18v output I can replace the transformer no problem.

Comment: Feeding tl431 through 470k + 500k pot makes the KA current a few uA only. For proper work it should be 1mA at least. Try to lower these resistors to 10k.

Comment: Please show your simulation.

Comment: You could build a simple opamp+mosfet current regulator. You will find plenty of examples online if you search for it. Could possibly also power the opamp from the output rails (if it can tolerate such voltage).

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use e-fuses (or any fuses) prior to the regulators, or you can do it the classic "active" way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNFyRF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose R1 and R3 according to maximum current permitted \$I_{MAX}\$:

$$ R_1 = R_3 = \frac{0.7}{I_{MAX}} $$

The value of 1.2Ω shown will limit current to about 600mA.

You should also consider the power that R1 and R3 will dissipate under full load. Here, 600mA through R1 would cause it to dissipate power \$P_{R1}\$:

$$ P_{R1} = I^2R_1 = (600mA)^2 \times 1.2\Omega = 0.43W $$

R1 should be rated 0.5W or more.

The most power will be dissipated in transistors M1 and M2, when the outputs are short-circuited. In that state M1 and M2 will dissipate about:

$$ P_{M1} = IV \approx 20V \times 600mA \approx 12W $$

The regulators will also be dissipating similar power when their outputs are near ground.

This is the biggest obstacle when building current limiting systems, and linear voltage regulators. The elements responsible for regulating can get very very hot. In this case, you really need to but the regulators *and* M1 and M2 on heat sinks, and maybe even put a fan in there.

Also, I haven't drawn in the usual capacitors that should accompany the regulators; don't omit them!

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer.. I really appreciate it , however the power dissipation appears to be too too much, is there another topology you can suggest that doesn't require a too big heatsink? 
I used a DC-DC converters that was capable of 5A and 0-30v with current control, and the heatsink at them was small like 2.5x2.5cm

Comment: Another question please, you said I can use efuses prior regulators, but can and how could that work with the negative supply voltage?

Comment: @Shamooooot A fuse doesn't care what the voltage is. It heats up from current through its own resistance, in either direction. So, you can place a fuse in any path of current (at a regulator input, for example), and when that current exceeds the fuse's rating, it breaks the path.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant Efuse something like TPS25983.. not the conventional fuse..

Comment: @Shamooooot that's a big question, way too big for comments.

Comment: I used a heat sink calculator to calculate the sinks for the FETs and it gave 8cmx8cmx3cm is that what 's expected or how big do you think it should be (without using a fan)

Answer (score 3):

One of simplest is to make followers with two Darlingtons, references from zeners, and current limiters from 1ohms+bjts (I_lim= 0.6V/1ohm=0.6A).

The input voltage should in +-24V to +-35V range.

[image]

Comment: In that circuit, there is no feedback from the output to the regulator circuit.  Both the line and load regulation are much worse than in the circuit linked to by the OP.

Comment: @AnalogKid That’ right, it doesn’t catch a chip solution regarding precision. But you forgot to mention this can output the voltage from zero volts. That is a big advantage in practise, sometimes even more important than holding precise output.

Comment: Sometimes, but the OP already is content with a 317 output range.

Answer (score 3):

Every datasheet I've seen for the LM317 and 337 includes an application circuit for a current limiter.  Here is a link to the current version of the 317 datasheet.  See figure 14:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf?ts=1707978272869&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM317

Here is an image grab from that document.

[image]

If you put this circuits (1-317 and 1-337) in front of the ones in your schematic, there will be two 317/337's in series for each output voltage, one as a current limiter followed by one as the voltage regulator.  You will need a minimum of +/-24 V across the filter capacitors.

This is fewer parts than the classic 2-transistor current limit circuit.  AND, the LM317 is an excellent current regulator.  Regulation is based on the value of its internal voltage reference, which is more accurate and far more temperature-stable that the forward voltage of a transistor's base-emitter junction that the classic circuit relies on.

Compared to the traditional circuit, this approach requires a higher voltage across the current regulator.  But the performance is a huge improvement.

Update:

Power dissipation in the components can be calculated with Watts Law:

P = E x I

and Joule's Law:

P = I^2 x R

The image shows a variable resistor, but many normal small pots cannot handle 750 mA.  Better to start with a fixed resistor for a fixed current limit value.  Use the given equation to select a standard resistor value.  For example, a 1.6 ohm resistor yields a current limit value of 750 mA.

Using Joule's Law, the power dissipation at max current is 0.9 W.  For better long-term reliability, use a resistor rated for a minimum of 2 W.

Power dissipation in the ICs depends on the voltage across the filter capacitors.  Please update your question with your transformer output voltage under load and the value of the filter capacitors.  As a cross-check, also show the voltage across the filter caps.

Below the current limit value, the voltage across the current 317 is fairly constant, and the power dissipation is directly proportional to the output current (Watt's Law).  The voltage across the voltage 317 varies inversely with the output voltage.  Its power dissipation depends on both the output voltage and current.

When the limiter kicks in, things change.  The minimum power dissipation in the limit and voltage 317's will be at least 2 W each, demanding heatsinks.

More later, after more information.

Comment: thank you very much, could you elaborate about the expected power dissipation through the regulators and the required resistors wattages roughly?.

Comment: There's a rather big dropout across the 317 and resistor, maybe 3V or so. With a similar dropout for the voltage regulator, that's getting close to a total of 6V at full load. With supply ripple, for 18V out the supply should probably be closer to 26V.

Comment: The OP doesn't say anything about his xfmr, which is why I mentioned a minimum cap voltage.  The overall headroom is a bit high, but the circuit simplicity is unmatched.  For a relatively inexperienced person, this might be the more important criterion.

Comment: I have updated the question @AnalogKid , but I wanted to ask about the worst case scenario power dissipation required, you mentioned to be at least 2W but what is the power dissipation if the output was short circuited?.

Answer (score 2):

... @Michal Podmanický and @AnalogKid have tickled my imagination, which is freewheeling roughly in this direction:

[image: Linear stabilizer with current limit, long-tailed pair against a current mirror]

I.e. a long-tailed diff pair to do voltage comparison and negative feedback regulation, plus a current mirror whose emitter ends are used as another differential input, adjustable by a trim-pot, sensing the voltage drop across a shunt resistor. A double diff amp using just four extra BJT's :-) Hans Camenzind is my hero.
I haven't simulated the circuit and haven't calculated the resistors, apologies...