# Is it possible to use an Efuse for protection with negative voltage?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, negative-voltage, efuse

Following to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/701552/how-to-add-a-current-limit-for-a-dual-rails-power-supply), is it possible to use an efuse with a negative voltage power, to eliminate the need of the required big heatsinks?

Comment: how would a fuse eliminate the need for a heatsink?

Comment: I am trying to use the Efuse instead of the current limiting circuit proposed by Simon Fitch, as the transistors in the circuit dissipate 12w.