# DC/DC buck/bost mudules vs LM317 comparing for Bench power supply circuit

Tags: power-supply

I Have this two circuit, one of them based of lm317 like [this](http://www.rcpano.net/2019/08/08/how-to-make-a-variable-power-supply-1-25v-0-10a-voltage-current-adjustable-power-supply/):

[image]

and have some Circuit based of XL4005 or XL4015 IC like this:

Input: main using a 18V 2A transformer
Output: 0-18V
Current: 0-1.5A
Current Limiting controlled by a potentiometer
Voltage output controlled by a potentiometer
[image]

But i want the same output/input parameters for both of them like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100649/lm317-based-power-supply-with-current-limiting) :

> Input: main using a 24V 5A transformer or AC/DC power supply  (almost 75W)
>
> Output: 0-18V Current: 0-1.5A
>
> Current Limiting controlled by a potentiometer
>
> Voltage output controlled by a potentiometer

In [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/LM317-Based-DIY-Variable-Benchtop-Power-Supply/) post said about advantage of dc/dc boost/buck modules :

> We used linear regulators like LM317, LM2940 etc. As I said before
>       these are so inefficient and can't be used for a battery powered
>       setup. So what you can do is, find one of those cheap DC-DC buck
>       modules from any online shops and replace the linear regulators with
>       them. They're more efficient (>90%), has better load regulation,
>       more current capability, current limiting, short circuit protection
>       and all. LM2596 is one of that kind. The buck (step down) modules
>       will have a precision potentiometer on top. You can replace it with
>       a "multi-turn potentiometer" and use it at the front panel instead
>       of normal linear pots. That'll give you more control over the output
>       voltage.

One of the important thing is having max current for 0- max voltage without considerable decrease,but i have seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-t1wiGrxB2E) current voltage output chart for XL4005 or XL4015 base:

[image]

but don't know that chart for LM317 based!

So i like to know your suggestion about which one of this two schematic or system or better for bench power supply?

And can solve the current drop based of boot/buck converter modules (like XL4005) for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: If you really need 50 A ratings on your output components, that's at least 10x what a '317 can handle, and 100x what it makes sense to use it for with today's cheap switching regulators available. So the 317 isn't a real option for your project.

Comment: NO it was an example and i want the output the same for both of them.(updated the Q)

Comment: Very similar to your earlier question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504796/an-adjustable-power-supply-with-tracking

Answer (score 1):

To answer you main question about LM317 performance.

The current vs voltage output chart for LM317 is much worse than for the switching module.  You're limited to less-than or equal the input current at all voltages,  and are limited to less if it starts to overheat because the heatsink is too small. (so the slope may actually be backwards compared to what you posted.  and all the numbers are worse)

some comments on your drawing.

You have drawn a "boost converter" where you probably want a buck converter

If the current is less than 10A you can use a voltmeter-ammeter module that has an integrated shunt.

you may have to place the shunt in the negative side of the output

If you connect the ground end of the voltage setting potentiometer to a small voltage instead of to ground you will be able to adjust the voltage down to zero. (eg use a resistive divider off the 12V supply to make 1.5V )

Comment: I see somewhere by using two or three diodes series with the output line it would have zero voltage instead of 1.5 volt, but i don't get your means by setting ground end of potentiometer to ..., do you means give the negative voltage to that pin?

Comment: no put a positive voltage there enough to hit the threshold of the feedback pin.  which is usually about 1.25V,  you've got the 12V  that runs the voltmeter so you could use some of that via a divider.

Answer (score 1):

A power supply project like that is a great learning experience. Go for it!

You won't get 24V input, 2V output @ 1.5A from the LM317. That's 22V x 1.5A = 33W. The Rja of an LM317 on a heatsink will be far too high. You'll have to derate the current at lower output voltages or parallel up some LM317s or use external pass devices (a la some 2N3055's). You can search the internet and find many examples of such things.

If you did solve the thermal problem then you'll have the benefit of a very low broadband noise supply and a supply with nearly zero output voltage ripple. This is what most of the good bench supplies are doing and why they have big, heavy heat sinks on the back.

A switcher is going to be pretty easy - just buy a module, hook it up and use it. A super low cost module may not have the best load transient response, it may be quite noisy (output voltage ripple) under some conditions. It may even behave very poorly under some conditions. But unless you are doing work that is very sensitive to noise then that's fine. If you do run into noise sensitivity issues then you can add a linear regulator to that circuit to clean things up.

In either case, you can probably only get to ~1.2V or so, not 0V, without some additional circuit tricks because these devices have internal references of that voltage, usually.

As mentioned earlier, you want a buck converter instead of a boost converter. It would be a great learning experience to build both, test them and gain some insight and appreciation!