# LM337 based current-limiting power supply

Tags: power-supply, analog

I would like to convert the LM317 circuit found in the accepted answer of [this similar thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100649/lm317-based-power-supply-with-current-limiting) into its negative equivalent based on the LM337, in order to make a non-tracking +/- lab power supply.

Is it as simple as replacing the LM317 and swapping all polarities? I.e., starting from this schematic:
[image]

**Update:** Here is what I have for both positive and negative rails (including the generation of the +/-12V necessary for the JFETs). Is this correct?
[image]

I couldn't find the JFETs anywhere on Farnell or RS - I guess they're outdated. Could you suggest a suiting equivalent and why (so that I can learn from that)?

Many thanks

P.S: I am aware this is dissipating a lot of heat worst-case - I'll mount the TO-220 on a heatsink fan-cooled to get the Rth below 3°C/W and never touch the ICs. There is actually 0.5A out of those, 0.82R is supposed to be 2.5R.

Comment: You'll need P channel JFETs of course

Comment: Right, true, true... Do you know the equivalent of the 2N3822 as P-channel?

Comment: And also, shouldn't I keep the gate of the JFET to +10V when using P-channel JFETs?

Comment: If you can't find suitable equivalents, recognise that connection as a constant current source, for which there are easy alternatives. (Yes, gate and source to +10V)

Comment: Q1 and Q2 are configured as a 2-terminal constant current diode.  As such, they do not have to be changed to p-channel parts for a negative output circuit, just inserted into the circuit with the correct poolarity.

Comment: @AnalogKid: great! Do you mean I should reverse the entire {pot,D1,D2,Q1} block, and {pot,D3,D4,Q2} as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer with my current schematic. Could you either confirm or correct it? Thanks !

Comment: Unless you have an issue with heating in your room, why would you use this old junk for laboratory supply? Even in TO-220 with heatsinks, these can only give maybe 400-500mA before they melt through the floor.

Comment: Because I don't have the money for a triple lab bench supply, and I don't know how to limit the current otherwise than by using a current limiter with series LDO. I've noticed I use either high voltage at high current or lower voltage at low current most of the time, so it seems to fit most of my use cases.

Comment: So buy 3x cheap quality single channel 30V supplies... Or just use any boost converter with current limit option through a pin. Or you know, do any form of simple paid work for the same amount of time it would take you to build this thing, then buy a state of the art bench supply with the money.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sorry but this is off-topic. Are you able to answer the question?

Comment: My bounty is about to expire - is the question not worth 100 rep (genuine question)?

Comment: Even though your drawing is quite neat, I would advise you to use a program like circuitlab, ltspice, or kicad to draw your schematics. Bonus: Simulations.

Comment: Bonus of hand drawings, much faster to draw :) But you're right, I just did not find the LM337 and LM338 in LTSPICE last I checked. The drawing's now in DesignSpark PCB, ready to manufacture, but I don't really want to hit the button until someone checks off the design...